# SQL joining multiple tables along with multiple paramters

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm a controls engineer and have only minimal knowledge on SQL, but have taken upon some reporting with AB FactoryTalk, SQL Express 2012, and Report Builder 3.0.    Data is from a PLC and logs data into three tables

- Float Table
- String Table
- Tag Table

The tag table holds the tag name and a "TagIndex" for reference.  The Float table holds all the numeric data and has a "TagIndex" with a number that matches the tag name in the tag table.  Same concept with the String table, holds strings and has a "TagIndex" that matches to the tag name in the Tag Table.

I am building a table that displays an entire data log snapshot which includes some data from the Float Table and the String Table.  Both are related to each other in that their Date/Time logged matches.
I need to relate the Tag table to both the String and Float tables, as well as relate the String Table to the Float table by the logged date.

using the query designer in Report Builder, I have a semi working table with the following

```
SELECT
    StringTable.DateAndTime AS [StringTable DateAndTime]
    ,FloatTable.DateAndTime AS [FloatTable DateAndTime]
    ,FloatTable.TagIndex AS [FloatTable TagIndex]
    ,FloatTable.Val AS [FloatTable Val]
    ,StringTable.Val AS [StringTable Val]
    ,TagTable.TagIndex AS [TagTable TagIndex]
    ,TagTable.TagName
    ,TagTable.StartEnd
    ,TagTable.TableOrder
    ,TagTable.Label
    ,TagTable.Unit
    ,StringTable.TagIndex AS [StringTable TagIndex]
FROM TagTable
    FULL OUTER JOIN FloatTable
      ON TagTable.TagIndex = FloatTable.TagIndex
    FULL OUTER JOIN StringTable
      ON TagTable.TagIndex = StringTable.TagIndex
```

^Code works but with no relation of FloatTable and StringTable.
also replacing the last two lines with the the below and was a valid query but did not yield what I needed:

```
FULL OUTER JOIN StringTable
  ON TagTable.TagIndex = StringTable.TagIndex
  AND FloatTable.DateAndTime = StringTable.DateAndTime
```

The data is used in a table with the columns as the TagIndex/TagNames and the rows are the DateAndTime.

How do I get the DateAndTime to join correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full outer join is indeed a good idea here, but only for the two child tables.

```
SELECT
     s.DateAndTime AS [StringTable DateAndTime]
    ,f.DateAndTime AS [FloatTable DateAndTime]
    ,f.TagIndex AS [FloatTable TagIndex]
    ,f.Val AS [FloatTable Val]
    ,s.Val AS [StringTable Val]
    ,t.TagIndex AS [TagTable TagIndex]
    ,t.TagName
    ,t.StartEnd
    ,t.TableOrder
    ,t.Label
    ,t.Unit
    ,s.TagIndex AS [StringTable TagIndex]
FROM FloatTable f
FULL OUTER JOIN StringTable s ON s.TagIndex = f.TagIndex AND s.DateAndTime = f.DateAndTime
INNER JOIN TagTable t ON t.TagIndex IN (s.TagIndex, f.TagIndex);
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! When I use the f.DateAndTime for my rows, it is still not equating the dates, but this may be likely due to my rows not being set up right in some manner.  Is it recommended to shorten names with the s,f,t?  It certainly reads better.  I'm also chasing a new avenue and dumping all the data to a temp Pivot table to be easier to sort and filter.

Comment: Check `DateAndTime` if they are really equal in the tables. Maybe they differ just in some microseconds and hence don't match.

Comment: As to alias names: yes, it is recommended using alias names when dealing with multiple tables. It's up to you what names you use. Only make sure they are not too long and are mnemonics for the table (as f for float, s for string in the example).